# Firebase Cloud Functions not writing in database

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to write a Firebase Cloud function which would write the current time inside the database whenever called:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.pushDateOfCall = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

    const currentTime = new Date();

    return admin.database().ref('/dates').push({currentTime: currentTime}).then((snapshot) => {
        return res.send("Complete");
      }).catch((error) => res.send("Something went wrong"));
  });
```

After deploying the function and calling it from the function's URL, nothing is written inside the database.

Output of firebase functions logs:

```
Function execution took 1358 ms, finished with status code: 304
```

P.S. I am running the link from incognito since I wish that whoever calls the link (both authorised and unauthorised) is able to use it.

Comment: Log the error on catch block

Comment: @hkchakladar I logged it but it is not an error. The `.then` will execute successfully and the `.catch` would never trigger. However, nothing is written inside the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@hkchakladar is right, changing to `{currentTime: String(currentTime)}` will solve the problem.

However, note that you don't need to return `res.send()` nor to return the promise returned by the asynchronous `push()` method. This is shown in the official Firebase video about HTTP Cloud Function, see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA

So your code may be as follows:

```
exports.pushDateOfCall = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const currentTime = new Date();

  admin
    .database()
    .ref('dates')
    .push({ currentTime: String(currentTime) })
    .then(ref => {
      res.send('Complete');
    })
    .catch(error => res.status(500).send('Something went wrong'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const currentTime = new Date();
```

Here `currentTime` is an object. If you want to store the String of the date, use `String(currentTime)` as

```
return admin.database().ref('/dates').push({currentTime: String(currentTime)})
```